# Convert dataframe cell containing dictionary to dataframe with new columns pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Here is the data frame. Which contain some cells having a dictionary in them. I want to convert the dictionary items to columns

```
dfx={'name':['Alex','Jin',np.nan,'Peter'],
     'age':[np.nan,10,12,13],
     'other':[{'school':'abc','subject':'xyz'},
     np.nan,
     {'school':'abc','subject':'xyz'},
     np.nan,]
     }

dfx=pd.DataFrame(dfx)
```

Output

```
name    age        other
Alex             {'school': 'abc', 'subject': 'xyz'}
Jin     10.0    
        12.0     {'school': 'abc', 'subject': 'xyz'}
Peter   13.0
```

Here is the Desired output

```
name    age      school    subject
Alex             abc         xyz
Jin     10.0        
        12.0     abc         xyz
Peter   13.0
```

Comment: wont be very fast, so if your frame is large I do not recommend this  but you could do `dfx.join(dfx['other'].apply(pd.Series)).drop(columns=['other', 0])`

Comment: i am trying this way
`pd.DataFrame(list(dfx['other'].dropna()))`
but it reset the index, making it impossible to put back

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `.str.get` accessor to actually index into the dictionaries in your columns. This also returns `nan` whenever the cell value is `nan` instead of a dictionary:

```
clean_df = (dfx
            .assign(
               school=lambda df: df["other"].str.get("school"),
               subject=lambda df: df["other"].str.get("subject"))
            .drop("other", axis=1))

print(clean_df)
    name   age school subject
0   Alex   NaN    abc     xyz
1    Jin  10.0    NaN     NaN
2    NaN  12.0    abc     xyz
3  Peter  13.0    NaN     NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
df_final = dfx[['name','age']].assign(**pd.DataFrame(dfx.other.to_dict()).T)

Out[41]:
    name   age school subject
0   Alex   NaN    abc     xyz
1    Jin  10.0    NaN     NaN
2    NaN  12.0    abc     xyz
3  Peter  13.0    NaN     NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a `dictionary` of `dfx`'s`index` and `other`. `pd.DataFrame` dictionary and `transpose`. That will give you a new `dataframe`. Join the resulting `dataframe` to the first two columns of dfx.

```
dfx.iloc[:,:-1].join(pd.DataFrame(dict(zip(dfx.index,dfx.other))).T).fillna('')



    name age school subject
0   Alex        abc     xyz
1    Jin  10               
2         12    abc     xyz
3  Peter  13
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply `Series` to the column with dictionaries:

```
df.drop('other', 1).join(df['other'].apply(pd.Series).drop(0, 1))
```

Output:

```
    name   age school subject
0   Alex   NaN    abc     xyz
1    Jin  10.0    NaN     NaN
2    NaN  12.0    abc     xyz
3  Peter  13.0    NaN     NaN
```